# Как добавить в код подпрограмму?

Tags: python

Помогите добавить функцию или процедуру в код. Я не понимаю какую сюда функцию или процедуру добавить

Дано N чисел: сначала вводится число N,
затем вводится ровно N целых чисел.
Подсчитайте количество нулей среди
введенных чисел и выведите это
количество. Вам нужно подсчитать
количество чисел, равных нулю, а не
количество цифр.

```
print('количество чисел ')
N = int(input())
a=0
for i in range(N):
  print('Введите число ')
  c = int(input())
  if c==0: 
    a+=1 
print(a)
```

Comment: Может быть, вынесите в отдельную функцию ввод N чисел и подсчёт заданных значений, чтобы эта функция возвращала количество найденных значений.

Answer (score -1):

Не очень понятен вопрос. Что именно надо сделать?

Если нужно через функции сделать, то вот:

```
amountZero = 0
n = 0
number = 0

def amountZeros():
    global amountZero, n, number
    
    n = int(input("Количество чисел: "))
    
    for i in range(n):
        number = int(input("Число: "))
        
        if number == 0:
            amountZero += 1
    
    return amountZero

print(amountZeros())
```

Comment: фу, глобал.....

Comment: Ну, предлагай свой вариант)